# Why do popular e-commerce sites not use tagging to organize their content?

Tags: e-commerce, tagging

Does anybody know why famous and popular e-commerce web sites such as eBay, Amazon, Target, etc. avoids using tagging or does not adapt to this method of content organization?

Do you know any successful e-commerce web site that take advantage of tagging?

Comment: I have never had a problem finding things on Amazon because their search is so good. On the other hand search on Stack Overflow is diabolically bad so that's why they need humans to tag it! Jeff, are you listening?!!

Comment: This is not programming related, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq